# pass variable from javascript to ASP.NET behind code VB.Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to show and get coordinates of website visitors' location to store it in my database, I've done a simple trial using google maps API in javascript.
now I need to pass the coordinates values from javascript to my code to make the calculations required and store it in database.

Here's the locater code

```
   <script>
            function success(position) {
                var s = document.querySelector('#status');
                if (s.className == 'success') {
                    return;
                }
                s.innerHTML = "Gotcha!";
                s.className = 'success';

                var mapcanvas = document.createElement('div');
                mapcanvas.id = 'mapcanvas';
                mapcanvas.style.height = '400px';
                mapcanvas.style.width = '560px';

                document.querySelector('article').appendChild(mapcanvas);

                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

                var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 15,
                    center: latlng,
                    mapTypeControl: false,
                    navigationControlOptions: { style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL },
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcanvas"), myOptions);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latlng,
                    map: map,
                    title: "You are here! (at least within a " + position.coords.accuracy + " meter radius)"
                });
            }

            function error(msg) {
                var s = document.querySelector('#status');
                s.innerHTML = typeof msg == 'string' ? msg : "failed";
                s.className = 'fail';
            }

            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
            } else {
                error('not supported');
            }

            //the problem is here!
            var getter = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            document.getElementById('<%=send_laty.ClientID%>') = getter.lat;
            document.getElementById('<%=send_lony.ClientID%>') = getter.lng;
            alert(getter)


        </script>
```

I've created 2 hidden fields to carry the variables from javascript to code behind

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="send_laty" runat="server" Value="" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="send_lony" runat="server" Value="" />
```

and I'm testing them on the page_load of the aspx.vb page like this

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim output As String
    output = send_laty.Value + " ___  " + send_lony.Value
    MsgBox(output)

End Sub
```

but the output is _______ which means that the variables are not passed!

I need a hint about why it's not passing the values!

Thanks in advance,

Comment: The Page_Load of the aspx.vb page executes before the javascript so the value will always be blank.  You need to postback the values in order to send the data back to the server.

Comment: you're right ... I used a Request.Form("hidden") instead of the hidden.value and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the result to the `value` property.

```
document.getElementById('<%=send_laty.ClientID%>').value = getter.lat;
document.getElementById('<%=send_lony.ClientID%>').value = getter.lng;
```

Answer (score 0):

like what mga911 said

> The Page_Load of the aspx.vb page executes before the javascript so the value will always be blank. You need to postback the values in order to send the data back to the server

instead of using

```
dim x as string = send_lony.Value
```

and

document.getElementById('<%=send_laty.ClientID%>')

i used

```
dim x as string = Request.Form("send_lony")
```

with

```
document.getElementById('<%=send_laty.ClientID%>').value
```

I'm thankful for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

To pass value from javascript to page behind using dynamic control, do the following:

```
In aspx page header content,
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function executedelete(txt) {
        alert(txt);
        document.getElementById('<%=ctlHiddenField.ClientID%>').value = txt    
        __doPostBack("<%= deletetherecord.UniqueID %>", "");                            
    }                    
</script>
```

In aspx page body content,

```
<asp:Button ID="deletetherecord" runat="server" style="display:none" />           
<asp:HiddenField ID="ctlHiddenField" runat="server" />
```

In Page Behind,

```
Protected Sub deletetherecord_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles deletetherecord.Click
    Dim txt As String = ctlHiddenField.Value
    'do processing here        
End Sub
```

In Page Behind function, create dynamic control,

```
SomeLabel.Text &= "<input id=""deletebutton"" type=""button"" value=""Delete"" onClick=""executedelete('" & gv.Rows(row).Cells(5).Text & "');"" />"
```